# Getting StackOverflowException in a loop

Tags: vb.net, loops, stack-overflow, infinite-loop, mscorlib

I made a application to test the Martingale strategy, but I am getting this annoying exception in my app while running.

Full application code for testing:

Module Module1

```
Dim basebet, balance, rollunder, sleep As Integer
Dim increaseby As Decimal
Dim bet As Decimal

Dim confTarget As Integer

Sub Main()
    bootConf()
    Menu()
End Sub

Sub bootConf()

    basebet = 1          '1 Base Bet
    bet = 1              'Current Bet
    increaseby = 3       'Multiplier on loss
    balance = 50000      '100 Starting Balance
    rollunder = 4998     '1% House Edge
    sleep = 50           'Sleep between bets in MS

End Sub

Sub basebetConf(ByVal newVal As Integer)
    basebet = newVal
    Conf()
End Sub
Sub increasebyConf(ByVal newVal As Integer)
    increaseby = newVal
    Conf()
End Sub
Sub balanceConf(ByVal newVal As Integer)
    balance = newVal
    Conf()
End Sub
Sub rollunderConf(ByVal newVal As Integer)
    If newVal > 4999 Then
        Conf()
    ElseIf newVal < 1 Then
        Conf()
    Else
        rollunder = newVal
        Conf()
    End If
End Sub
Sub sleepConf(ByVal newVal As Integer)
    sleep = newVal
    Conf()
End Sub

Sub Conf()
    Console.Clear()
    Console.WriteLine("")
    Console.WriteLine("                                 Martingale Simulator")
    Console.WriteLine("                                 Developed by Art3mis")
    Console.WriteLine("")
    Console.WriteLine("                               CONFIGURATION")
    Console.WriteLine("                               ¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯")
    Console.WriteLine("                               BASE BET            : " & basebet)
    Console.WriteLine("                               LOSE MULTIPLIER     : " & increaseby)
    Console.WriteLine("                               BASE BALANCE        : " & balance)
    Console.WriteLine("                               ROLLUNDER (0-5000)  : " & rollunder)
    Console.WriteLine("                               SLEEP (IN MILLISEC) : " & sleep)
    Console.WriteLine("")
    Console.WriteLine("                                 Select value to edit (1-5)")
    Console.WriteLine("                                 Press X to return.")
    Console.Write("                                     > ")
    Dim input As ConsoleKeyInfo = Console.ReadKey()
    If input.Key = ConsoleKey.D1 Then
        confTarget = 1
    ElseIf input.Key = ConsoleKey.D2 Then
        confTarget = 2
    ElseIf input.Key = ConsoleKey.D3 Then
        confTarget = 3
    ElseIf input.Key = ConsoleKey.D4 Then
        confTarget = 4
    ElseIf input.Key = ConsoleKey.D5 Then
        confTarget = 5
    ElseIf input.Key = ConsoleKey.X Then
        Menu()
    Else
        Conf()
    End If
    Console.WriteLine("")
    Console.WriteLine("")
    Console.WriteLine("                                 Enter new value")
    Console.WriteLine("                                 Press X to return.")
    Console.Write("                                     > ")
    Dim input2 As Integer = Console.ReadLine()
    If confTarget = 1 Then
        basebetConf(input2)
    ElseIf confTarget = 2 Then
        increasebyConf(input2)
    ElseIf confTarget = 3 Then
        balanceConf(input2)
    ElseIf confTarget = 4 Then
        rollunderConf(input2)
    ElseIf confTarget = 5 Then
        sleepConf(input2)
    End If
        'Console.Read()

End Sub

Sub Menu()
    Console.Clear()
    Console.WriteLine("")
    Console.WriteLine("                                 Martingale Simulator")
    Console.WriteLine("                                 Developed by Art3mis")
    Console.WriteLine("")
    Console.WriteLine("                              ╔═ MENU ═════════════════╗")
    Console.WriteLine("                              ╠═ 1 : START             ║")
    Console.WriteLine("                              ╠═ 2 : CONFIGURATION     ║")
    Console.WriteLine("                              ╠═ 3 : ABOUT & CREDITS   ║")
    Console.WriteLine("                              ╚════════════════════════╝")
    Console.Write("                              > ")
    Dim input As ConsoleKeyInfo = Console.ReadKey()
    If input.Key = ConsoleKey.D1 Then
        Console.Clear()
        Console.WriteLine("")
        Console.WriteLine("                                 Martingale Simulator")
        Console.WriteLine("                                 Developed by Art3mis")
        Console.WriteLine("")
        Roll()
    ElseIf input.Key = ConsoleKey.D2 Then
        Conf()
    ElseIf input.Key = ConsoleKey.D3 Then
        About()
    Else
        Menu()
    End If


End Sub

Sub Roll()
    Dim rn As New Random
    Dim roll As Integer
    roll = rn.Next(0, 10000)
    If roll > rollunder Then
        'Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red
            Console.WriteLine("LOSE - " & roll & " - Bet: " & bet)
        'Console.ResetColor()
            balance -= bet
            bet = bet * increaseby
            Console.Title = "Martingale Sim - Balance: " & balance
    Else
        'Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green
            Console.WriteLine("WIN  - " & roll & " - Bet: " & bet)
        'Console.ResetColor()
            balance += bet
            bet = basebet
            Console.Title = "Martingale Sim - Balance: " & balance
    End If
    Threading.Thread.Sleep(sleep)
    checkRoll()
End Sub

Sub checkRoll()
    If balance < 0 Then
        MsgBox("Ran out of balance.")
    Else
        Roll()
    End If

End Sub

Sub About()


End Sub
End Module
```

Here's the spot where the application fails and throws the exception:

```
    If roll > rollunder Then
        'Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red
            Console.WriteLine("LOSE - " & roll & " - Bet: " & bet) *** HERE!
        'Console.ResetColor()
            balance -= bet
            bet = bet * increaseby
            Console.Title = "Martingale Sim - Balance: " & balance
    Else
        'Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green
            Console.WriteLine("WIN  - " & roll & " - Bet: " & bet) *** HERE!
        'Console.ResetColor()
            balance += bet
            bet = basebet
            Console.Title = "Martingale Sim - Balance: " & balance
    End If
    Threading.Thread.Sleep(sleep)
    checkRoll()
```

I'm aware that this happens because it's in a infinite loop. I didnt find anything to help me in this situation, so I don't really know what to do.

Here's a screenshot showing the bug: http://prntscr.com/aw7mqd

Thanks in advance!

A

Comment: `roll()` is calling `checkRoll()` which is calling `roll()` which is calling `checkRoll()` (if the conditions are right, which they are almost everytime?). You need to restructure the calls sothat you have a function which has the infinite loops, like `while(true) { roll(); if( balance < 0) break;}` and take out the `checkRoll()` call within `roll()`. That would solve the infinite recursion problem, since `roll()` is now reapididly called without making any further calls invoking itself again. The problem is that the stack grows with every `CALL` you make, not an infinite loop per sé.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To give an example of what @Maximilian is referring to, change your `Roll` and `checkRoll` methods to look something like the following, which avoids the need for recursion.

```
Sub Roll()
    Do
        ...
    Loop While checkRoll()
End Sub

Function checkRoll() As Boolean
    If balance < 0 Then
        MsgBox("Ran out of balance.")
        Return False
    End If
    Return True
End Function
```